# Docusign not voiding envelope

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I followed the code on docusigns website about voiding envelopes with Node.js.
https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-common-api-tasks-void-an-envelope

But for some reason when I run the code it says the promise resolved with no issues no messages but the envelope doesn't actually get voided.

```
let apiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
apiClient.setBasePath(config.docusign.apiUrl);
apiClient.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);

let envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
let env = new docusign.Envelope();
env.status = 'voided';
env.voidedReason = 'Declined Offer';

return envelopesApi.update(config.docusign.accountID, envelopeId, env).then(() => {
    return true
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

The promise returns true but again doesn't actually void the envelope

Comment: What state is the envelope? was it sent? was it signed by anyone?

Comment: are you sure the envelopeId is correct?

Comment: Can you print information about the envelope before and after the envelopesApi.update call?

Comment: Status is "Sent" and the id is 100% correct or it would error out saying not found

Comment: @Nima Both the envelope info stays the exact same before and after the update call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. This is indeed an issue in our node sdk. The way to work around this bug is (ugly workaround, we will fix this bug soon):

```
let env = new docusign.Envelope();
env.status = 'voided';
env.voidedReason = 'Declined Offer';

const finalEnv = {envelope : env}

return envelopesApi.update('accountId', 'EnvId', finalEnv).then(() => {
    console.log('Yes the thing was voided');
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

The envelope body needs an "envelope" tag to work. We will work on address this issue. Thank you for bringing this to our attention.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue I ended up just doing a direct request to the docusign api with superagent instead of using the docusign-esign package that was suggested. I'm not sure if the esign is using the wrong request type.

```
    request
    .put(`${config.docusign.apiUrl}/v2.1/accounts/${config.docusign.accountID}/envelopes/${envelopeId}`)
    .send({"status": "voided", "voidedReason": "The reason for voiding the envelope"})
    .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`)
    .end((err, res) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(`ERROR: ${err}`)
        }
        console.log(res);
    });
```